# Roblox How to fix If statement?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm currently having some problems with a weapon I'm working on for my game. The weapon isn't a tool, but instead is connected to a StarterCharacter. I've made the following script to check if the weapon is equipped, then allow the player to attack.

```
Mouse.Button1Down:connect(function()
    if isEquipped == true then
        if not pause then
            pause = true
            anim1:Play()
            wait(0.1)
            trail.Enabled = true
            wait(0.6)
            trail.Enabled = false
            pause = false
        end
    end 
end)

handle.Touched:connect(function(hit)
    if isEquipped == true then
        if not pause2 then
            pause2 = true
            if Mouse.Button1Down then
                if humanoid and humanoid.Health > 0 and hit and not hit:isDescendantOf(person) then
                    local target = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
                    if target and target.Health > 0 then
                        target:TakeDamage(damage)
                        wait(0.7)
                        pause2 = false
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end)

game.Players.LocalPlayer:GetMouse().KeyDown:Connect(function(KeyPressed)
        if KeyPressed == "e" then
            if not pause3 then
                pause3 = true
                if toggle == false then
                    toggle = true
                    isEquipped.Value = true
                    fake1.Transparency = 1
                    fake2.Transparency = 1
                    disc1.Transparency = 0
                    disc2.Transparency = 0
                    wait(0.7)
                    pause3 = false
                else
                    pause3 = true
                    toggle = false
                    isEquipped.Value = false
                    fake1.Transparency = 0
                    fake2.Transparency = 0
                    disc1.Transparency = 1
                    disc2.Transparency = 1
                    wait(0.7)
                    pause3 = false
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

The problem is that I can equip the weapon, but when it's equipped, I can't attack with it.
Would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: mouse.KeyDown is deprecated, consider using a different method of getting input: https://www.robloxdev.com/api-reference/class/UserInputService

Also, is this _your_ script, or is it a freemodel script?

Comment: I will guess that responses are not coming quickly here on SO for the same reason you have finding logical errors in your own code: deeply nested `if` statements. It’s not an answer to your question, but getting an answer may actually just come to you if you reduce the nesting. At the very least, use some some other `else` statements to catch unexpected behavior.

Comment: @CoordinateNewton It's my script, but I used a damage method from the Roblox battle sword. Still need an answer.

Comment: To debug this program, I would recommend placing a print statement after each if statement. For example, after `if isEquipped == true then`, write `print("isEquipped is true")`. If you do this after each if statement, you will be able to see where the code is stopping. What happens if you try this?

Answer (score 1):

In the code you shown, there is no section or part of the code that actually sets isEquipped to true. You should bind this value to `tool.Equipped` event.

If you want more information about this, I suggest you to visit Roblox Wiki.

Also, are you using a LocalScript, or a Script? If you're using a LocalScript, you should use RemoteEvents for things that affect other clients, for example, sounds, settings a part's properties, creating parts, etc, etc. You can find more detailed infomration about this Client-Server communication model in Roblox Wiki.

Also, what is `pause3`'s value when the program start? What value do you asign to this variable? It should be set to false since the program starts, otherwise you will not be able to attack.